# How to put country flag image aside <select> language switcher without extension

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, language

I'am new to Magento and using 1.9.3.1. 
Found solution about placing flag image as language switcher(onclick) in

app/design/frontend/package_folder/theme_folder/template/page/switch/**languages.phtml**

With this code:

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php if ($_lang->getCode() != 'default'): ?>
        <a class="lang-flag" href="<?php echo $this->getCurrentUrl() . '?___store=' . $_lang->getCode();?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" alt=""></a>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

As you can see, ther is no `<select></select>` tag.

Here is default template **languages.phtml** with `<select></select>`tag

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <!-- Code to render flag image -->
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I need to place code to render picture, and to be right betore `<select></select>` tag depends of store view (but not to be clickable to switch language as first block of code above), and when i chose language in `<select></select>` tag (to switch language), then flag of another country must be displayed depends of language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <div class="flag-wrapper">
        <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
            <?php if($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```